# Scripting wget to populate a webapp

Tags: scripting, wget

Can I use wget to populate some forms in a web app if the web app requires a user to login?  I'm trying to use wget in a script to send some data to a web app, but it appears the web app rejects the attempts because I am not logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would be better off using `curl` instead of `wget`. Wget is meant more for downloading, not submitting forms.